# Calling a Typescript object function with a string name

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service in my class with multiple functions. The names of the functions come in a string array and I am trying to call them each without much success.

```
cars.forEach( car => {
    this.carService[ car.name ](
        height,
        plateNr
    );
} );
```

This version I get the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.carService[car.name] is not a function
```

If I try with template literal( this.carService[ `${car.name}` ] ):

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.carService[("" + car.name)] is not a function
```

If I directly input the individual function name it does work.

`this.carService[ 'Honda' ]` // ok

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(car.name)` to see what the value is?

Comment: Yes I did, it is the correct function name string.

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz of the problem?

Comment: Is your function names begin with capital letter? Honda vs. honda?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwl7kn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
Here it is

Comment: `"Toyota "` has a space at the end.  Shall we close this question as a typo, maybe?

Comment: @jcalz - I just found the same. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bqegf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the original still doesn't work somehow, Stakblitz is probably too simplified.

Comment: But nobody but you has access to the original, and the code you've posted is apparently insufficient to reproduce the problem?  The only thing I can do to help here is to encourage you to produce a [mcve].  Good luck.

Comment: True. Solved it by returning the functions from the service and calling them that way instead.

Answer (score 1):

If `carService` is defined as an object literal, it will lack an index signature (i.e. what to use as the result of an arbitrary string lookup). TypeScript doesn't know that your keys have a special meaning in the context of the object so it is most likely not able to infer that the result of the lookup might be a function.

When I do something similar locally, I don't get the same complaint though:

```
        const a = { b: () => {}, c: () => {}};
        const x = ["b", "c"];
        x.forEach(functionName => (a[functionName])());
```

The complaint I get is: “Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ b: () => void; c: () => void; }' has no index signature.”

There are two ways to fix:

1. Define your service as a dictionary with an index signature:

```
        const a: { [functionName: string]: Function } = { b: () => {}, c: () => {}};
        const x = ["b", "c"];
        x.forEach(functionName => (a[functionName])());
```

2. Explicitly define the incoming list of keys as being valid keys for the object:

```
        const a = { b: () => {}, c: () => {}};
        const x = ["b", "c"] as (keyof typeof a)[];
        x.forEach(functionName => (a[functionName])());
```

Which is preferable depends on how exactly you want to use the service and the key list.

Comment: My service is an Angular 7 service, so I guess the types should be known.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Angular will have a type definition for them yes, but if it's not explicitly defined as a dictionary what you're doing here won't work (except with the `keyof typeof` workaround). If you want you can also assign the service to a temporary variable with a better type for the operation (i.e. `const carServiceAsDictionary: {[key: string]: Function} = this.carService`) and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working fine

```
cars.forEach( car =>
     { 
let carName = car.name;
    this.carService[ carName ]( height, plateNr ); 
} );
```